# Evaluate Loss Function Value Getting From Training Set on Cross Validation Set

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, loss-function

I am following Andrew NG instruction to evaluate the algorithm in Classification:

1. Find the Loss Function of the Training Set.
2. Compare it with the Loss Function of the Cross Validation.
3. If both are close enough and small, go to next step (otherwise, there is bias or variance..etc).
4. Make a prediction on the Test Set using the resulted Thetas(i.e. weights) produced from the previous step as a final confirmation.

---

I am trying to apply this using `Scikit-Learn` Library, however, I am really lost there and sure that I am totally wrong (I didn't find anything similar online):

```
from sklearn import model_selection, svm
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, log_loss
from sklearn import datasets

def main():

    iris = datasets.load_iris()
    kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=42)
    model= svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
    results = model_selection.cross_val_score(estimator=model,
                                              X=iris.data,
                                              y=iris.target,
                                              cv=kfold,
                                              scoring=make_scorer(log_loss, greater_is_better=False))

    print(results)
```

### Error

```
ValueError: y_true contains only one label (0). Please provide the true labels explicitly through the labels argument.
```

I am not sure even it's the right way to start. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: The problem seems to be the scoring (loss function) here. It seems like this is a bug in `sklearn`, as you can [see here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the clarifications you provide in the comments and that you are not particularly interested in the log loss itself, I think the most straightforward approach is to abandon log loss and go for the accuracy instead:

```
from sklearn import model_selection, svm
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=42)
model= svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
results = model_selection.cross_val_score(estimator=model,
                                              X=iris.data,
                                              y=iris.target,
                                              cv=kfold,
                                              scoring="accuracy")  # change
```

Al already mentioned in the comments, inclusion of log loss in such situations still suffers from some unresolved issues in scikit-learn (see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9144) and [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6231)).

For the purpose of estimating the generalization ability of your model, you will be fine with the accuracy metric.

Comment: Thanks and plus one... I just got confused with the tutorial from Andrew about how to select the best model via making a comparison between CV and Training J-Cost Function and choose the smallest close one.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error appears often when you do cross validation.

Basically your data is split into `n_splits = 10` and some classes are missing on some of these splits. For example, your 9th split may not have training examples for class number 2.

So then when you evaluate your loss, the number of existing classes between your prediction and the test set do not match. So you cannot compute the loss if you have 3 classes in `y_true` and your model is trained to predict only 2.

What do you do in this case?

You have three possibilities:

1. Shuffle your data  `KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=42, shuffle = True`)
2. Make n_splits bigger
3. provide the list of labels explicitly to the loss function as follows

`args_loss = { "labels": [0,1,2] }
 make_scorer(log_loss, greater_is_better=False,**args_loss)`

4. Cherry pick your splits so you make sure this doesn't happen. I don't think Kfold allows this but [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) does

Comment: I like your interpretation of the problem but the thing is passing `"labels": [0,1,2]` throws `ValueError: The number of classes in labels is different from that in y_pred. Classes found in labels: [0 1 2]` .. also I believe you meant *make n_splits* **smaller** not **bigger**?

Comment: That was my idea in the first place, but it turns out that it isn't so: replacing with `scoring="accuracy"` while keeping `n_splits=10` works OK; also, reducing the `nsplits` and/or shuffling the data does not resolve the issue. The reason is the loss function itself, as @ncfirth has already commented in the OP

Comment: @desertnaut Do I really need to follow Andrew's instructions or just get the accuracy or F1-Score ..etc ?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve! If you are OK with accuracy, just go for it...

Comment: @desertnaut What I want to achieve is estimation of generalization ability of the algorithm for the unseen data to avoid over-fitting and under-fitting, i.e (**Model Selection**)

Answer (score 1):

Just for future readers who are following Andrew's Course:

`K-Fold` is **Not** practically applicable to this purpose, because we mainly want to evaluate the Thetas (i.e. Weights) produced by a certain algorithm with some ***parameters*** on the Cross-Validation Set by using those Thetas in a comparison between both Cost-Functions `J(train)` vs `J(CV)` to determine if the model suffers from *bias*, *variance* or it's *O.K*.

Nevertheless, `K-Fold` is mainly for ***testing*** the prediction on the CV using the weights produced from training the Model on Training Set.